# Creating a flexible table containing prices and periodes

Tags: database-design, database-tuning

I'm creating a system of availability for rooms and with a calendar according to the days, with every day have it's own price.

```
Room Type |  01  |  02  |  03  |  04  |  05  | ... |  31  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
Single    | $100 | $100 | $200 | $200 | $200 | ... | $300 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
Double    | $150 | $150 | $200 | $250 | $350 | ... | $320 |
```

The best thing that I come accross is :

```
RoomsAvailable
--------------
 # ID
 room_type
 from_date
 to_date
 price
```

But, despite this table is flexible with the periodes, it is not with every single day's price.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say that your specification is likely missing some elements such as a periodic calendar of holidays and other special events.  Likely the daily rate is changed due to matters like that.  (Think of a  Spring Break location and how prices might change.)

Comment: the client will enter the price for every day

Comment: Maybe it would be better to enforce that the client enters the date for every day at the application level as opposed to the database level, if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility.

[image]

The idea is that every time the price for a room changes, a PricingChange row would be added. From that date on, until there is another PricingChange row for the same RoomType, the price for that RoomType would be set to that row's price.

Sample data for this model:

[image]

With this sample data, Single rooms ware set at the price of $100 for June 1 2015, $50 for June 2 2015 to June 4 2015, and then back to $100 from June 5 2015 onwards. Double rooms are set to the price of $200 from June 1 2015 onwards.

Comment: Rather than a single date, these sorts of things are ususlly handled by having both a `FromDate` and a `ToDate` in the table.  The extra `UPDATE` when the price changes is more than worth it for simpler `SELECT`s and better indexing.

Comment: @MichaelGreen
The reason I see having a single date as opposed to a from and to date would be that it prevents storing conflicting data. What scenario would create a complicated select with having one date?

Comment: The determination of the current price: with a single date it requires a `MAX()` or `EXISTS()`.  With two dates the check is `>= .. AND .. <`, which tends to be faster.